# Django REST serializer not working with files

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, image-uploading

For example I have the following in `models.py`:

```
def upload_attachments(filename):
    return '/logos/%Y/%m_%d/{}'.format(filename) # well, not exactly, but close

class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_attachments)
```

Serializer for this model would look this way:

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = (
            'name',
            'logo'
        )
```

The view, that is working with this model:

```
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,))
@parser_classes((FormParser, MultiPartParser))
class ClientView(APIView):

def post(self, request, domain=None):

   data = request.DATA.get('data', None)
   serializer = ClientSerializer(data=data, files=request.FILES.get('file', None))

   if serializer.is_valid():
      serializer.save()
      return Response(utils.OK, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
   return Response({'error': serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I send form POST with key `file` containing the `logo.png` file and key `data` containing the JSON. I get either no arguement `files` although there are many examples on the net of that working and if I leave out the file (although I should get it) - I get the error with the `data` being unicode, not dict and if I wrap the `data` into the `json.loads()` - there are *"too many values to unpack"*.

**Update:** I found what was a problem with data. It was easy actually:

```
   data = request.DATA.get('data', None)
   data = data.get('data', None) # roughly, sure it could be prettyfied
   serializer = ClientSerializer(data=data, files=request.FILES.get('file', None))
```

The problem with the file still stands.

Comment: If you remove `FormParser` from your parser classes, does anything change?

Comment: No it was not the problem. I already found the answer, will add it a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

Well, good 'ol debug helped to find the problem with this code. Here is the final variant:

```
data = json.loads(request.DATA.get('data', None))
data = data.get('data', None)
data['logo']=request.FILES.get('file', None)
serializer = ClientSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    return Response(utils.OK, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

This is still a bit clumsy, but actually working chunk of code.